# Hibernate session per request vs Hibernate session per application?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to know that which is better for the web application using:- 
Spring3.1
Hibernate4

**Hibernate session per request** OR **Hibernate session per application**?

Please suggest

Thanks In Advance

Comment: hibernate session per application would be better. as the idea of hibernate having a session is to allow caching and other performance benefits by maintaining a session across application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **session per request** pattern is often a safe bet for any web application. It is maybe the most common pattern among all Servlet based applications.

When doing data manipulation we'll use the same session during the whole request and in the end of the request make sure that session and transaction is properly finalized. When implemented properly, session-per-request pattern guarantees that number of Hibernate sessions is in control, sessions are properly closed and sessions are flushed regularly. A good combo of characteristics for a multi-user web application.

You will find lots of good article on google for benefits of hibernate session per request pattern.